# Сортировка массива быстрым способом. Объясните суть условия по полочкам (отметил знаками "???")

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void quickSort(int mas[], int first, int last) {

    int f = first;
    int l = last;
    int mid = mas[(f + l) / 2];
    do {
        while (mas[f] < mid) f++;
        while (mas[l] > mid) l--;

        if (f <= l) {
            swap(mas[f], mas[l]);
            f++;
            l--;
        }
    } while (f < l);
    if (first < l) quickSort(mas, first, l); // ???
    if (f < last) quickSort(mas, f, last);   // ???
}


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int SIZE = 11;
    int arr[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 10;
        cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << "Исходный массив";
    cout << endl;

    int first = 0;
    int last = SIZE - 1;

    quickSort(arr, first, last);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << "Отсортированный массив";
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wqFEyeu3D8

Comment: Если вы точно понимаете,  что именно делает цикл `do { ... } while (f < l)` , то 2 строчки отмеченные //??? д.б. очевидны. (на всякий случай, первая сортирует начало, а вторая конец массива)